# Google Sheets count number of tables in HTML

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to return the number of tables in a HTML page to a google sheet. The code below can get me the number of tables in the chrome console.

```
var i = 1; [].forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName("table"),
   function(x) { (i++, x); });
console.log (i)
```

But I dont know how to get this result (i) in Google App Script so I can return it to my sheet. Something on the lines of

```
function doGet() {
  var html = UrlFetchApp.fetch('http://allqs.saqa.org.za/showUnitStandard.php?id=7743').getContentText();
  var table = getElementsByClassName(html, 'table')[0];

  var i = 1; [].forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName("table"),
       (i++, x);
    console.log (i)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to retrieve the number of tags of `<table>` fronm the URL of `http://allqs.saqa.org.za/showUnitStandard.php?id=7743` using GAS. If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Modification points :

- In the native GAS, `getElementsByTagName()` can't be used.

  - In this answer, the number of `<table>` was retrieved using regex.

#### Modified script :

```
var url = "http://allqs.saqa.org.za/showUnitStandard.php?id=7743";
var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
var numberOfTables = res.match(/<table/g).length;
Logger.log(numberOfTables) // 96 is retrieved.
```

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: @Derek Morgan Welcome. I'm glad your issue was solved. Thank you, too.